# How to run a palindrome test on a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a function that takes a string consisting of alphabetic
>   characters as input argument and returns True if the string is a
>   palindrome. A palindrome is a string which is the same backward or
>   forward. Note that capitalization does not matter here i.e. a lower
>   case character can be considered the same as an upper case character.

This is my code:

```
def Palindrome_test_string (input_str):
    output_str = ""
    count = 0
    for k in range (len(input_str) - 1, -1, -1):
        output_str = output_str + input_str[k]
    print ("The reverse of the string is:",output_str)

    for i in range (0, len(input_str)):
        if (output_str[i] == input_str[i]):
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    if (count == len(input_str)):
        return (True)
    else:
        return (False)


#Main Program
test_str = "Radar"
result = Palindrome_test_string (test_str)
print (result)
```

It shows the correct output for majority of cases but there's one problem with this program. When I input 'Radar' its reverse should be 'radaR' and according to the question, I have to consider upper and lowercase characters as equal while comparing. How to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if input_str.lower() == input_str[::-1].lower(): return True`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your input data to lower case.

```
def Palindrome_test_string (input_str):
    output_str = ""
    count = 0
    input_str = input_str.lower()
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def Palindrome_test_string(input_str):
    lower = input_str.lower()       # Store this to avoid doing it twice
    return lower == lower[::-1]

print(Palindrome_test_string('abccbA'))
```

This will display:

```
True
```

Note: The `[::-1]` string slice has the effect of reversing the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPalindrome(s):
   s = s.lower()
   x = s[::-1]

   if s == x:
      return True
   return False
```